# Remove newline characters in python RTL (right to left) language text

Tags: python

I'm trying to remove `\r` and `\n` characters from a text in python. However, when my program encounters a "persian" text, this is having no effect.

```
text = 'این تتلو ۴ میلیون طرفدار داره\nینی الگوی ۴ میلیون نفره\nینی رو ۴ میلیون نفر تاثیر میذاره حرفاش\nاین یعنی فاجعه'

text.replace("\r", '').replace("\n", '') # tried this, still not working
text.rstrip("\r\n") #not working
text.translate(str.maketrans("\n\t\r", "   ")) # not working

print(repr(text))# repr() displays \n and \r on output
```

the `\n` remains. I think this is a `rtl` (right to left) language. How do i remove these newline characters in this case?

Comment: `text.replace('\n', '')` works just fine for me. Python 3.6

Comment: `replace` and `translate` are working for me... Python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace` creates new `str` object:

```
text = 'این تتلو ۴ میلیون طرفدار داره\nینی الگوی ۴ میلیون نفره\nینی رو ۴ میلیون نفر تاثیر میذاره حرفاش\nاین یعنی فاجعه'
id(text)
140578645871120

id(text.replace("\r", '').replace("\n", ''))
4587132656
```

reassign it:

```
text2 = text.replace("\r", '').replace("\n", '')

text2
'این تتلو ۴ میلیون طرفدار دارهینی الگوی ۴ میلیون نفرهینی رو ۴ میلیون نفر تاثیر میذاره حرفاشاین یعنی فاجعه'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign the result of replace:

```
text = 'این تتلو ۴ میلیون طرفدار داره\nینی الگوی ۴ میلیون نفره\nینی رو ۴ میلیون نفر تاثیر میذاره حرفاش\nاین یعنی فاجعه'

text = text.replace('\n', '')

print(repr(text))
```

Comment: His example isn't working because he isn't assigning the result of `replace` to `text`. If he is assigning it, then the code snippet is not correct.

Comment: @vishes_shell: read the answer carefully: the point is not that he does the replace function differently, but that it needs to be assigned :)

Comment: I'm sorry, i should be careful, too.:)